# Fixing 'no symbolic type information' from dtrace in Linux?

Tags: linux, dtrace

Just documenting this: (self-answer to follow)

I'm aware that Sun's `dtrace` is not packaged for Ubuntu due to licensing issues; so I downloaded it and built it from source on Ubuntu - but I'm having an issue pretty much like the one in [Simple dtraces not working · Issue #17 · dtrace4linux/linux · GitHub](https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux/issues/17); namely loading of the driver seems fine:

```
dtrace-20130712$ sudo make load
tools/load.pl
23:20:31 Syncing...
23:20:31 Loading: build-2.6.38-16-generic/driver/dtracedrv.ko
23:20:34 Preparing symbols...
23:20:34 Probes available: 364377
23:20:44 Time: 13s
```

... however, if I try to run a simple script, it fails:

```
$ sudo ./build/dtrace -n 'BEGIN { printf("Hello, world"); exit(0); }'
dtrace: invalid probe specifier BEGIN { printf("Hello, world"); exit(0); }: "/path/to/src/dtrace-20130712/etc/sched.d", line 60: no symbolic type information is available for kernel`dtrace_cpu_id: Invalid argument
```

As per the issue link above:

> (ctf requires a private and working libdwarf lib - most older releases have broken versions).

... I then built `libdwarf` from source, and then `dtrace` based on it (not trivial, requires manually finding the right placement of symlinks); and I still get the same failure.

Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a trip to `gdb`, I figured that the problem occurs in `dtrace`'s function `dt_module_getctf` (called via `dtrace_symbol_type` and, I think, `dt_module_lookup_by_name`). In it, I noticed that most calls propagate the attribute/variable `dm_name = "linux"`; but when the failure occurs, I'd get `dm_name = "kernel"`!

Note that original line 60 from `sched.d` is:

```
    cpu_id = `dtrace_cpu_id; /* C->cpu_id; */
```

Then I found [thr3ads.net - dtrace discuss - accessing symbols without type info [Nov 2006]](http://thr3ads.net/dtrace-discuss/2006/11/382229-accessing-symbols-without-type-info); where this error message is mentioned:

> dtrace: invalid probe specifier fbt::calcloadavg:entry { 
>   printf("CMS_USER: %d, CMS_SYSTEM: %d, cpu_waitrq: %d\n", 
>   `cpu0.cpu_acct[0], `cpu0.cpu_acct[1], `cpu0.cpu_waitrq);}: in action 
>   list: no symbolic type information is available for unix`cpu0: No type 
>   information available for symbol

So:

- on that system, the request `` `cpu0.cpu_acct[0] `` got resolved to `` unix`cpu0 ``;
- and on my system, the request `` `dtrace_cpu_id `` got resolved to `` kernel`dtrace_cpu_id ``.

And since "*The backtick operator is used to read the
value of kernel variables, which will be specific to the running kernel.*" ([howto measure CPU load - DTrace General Discussion - ArchiveOrange](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/ejz8x2tzIGyquTS5hC08)), I thought maybe explicitly "casting" this "backtick variable" to `linux` would help.

And indeed it does - only a small section of `sched.d` needs to be changed to this:

```
translator cpuinfo_t < dtrace_cpu_t *C > {
    cpu_id = linux`dtrace_cpu_id; /* C->cpu_id; */
    cpu_pset = -1;
    cpu_chip = linux`dtrace_cpu_id; /* C->cpu_id; */
    cpu_lgrp = 0; /* XXX */
/*  cpu_info = *((_processor_info_t *)`dtrace_zero); /* ` */ /* XXX */
};

inline cpuinfo_t *curcpu = xlate <cpuinfo_t *> (&linux`dtrace_curcpu);
```

... and suddenly - it starts working!:

```
dtrace-20130712$ sudo ./build/dtrace -n 'BEGIN { printf("Hello, world"); exit(0); }'
dtrace: description 'BEGIN ' matched 1 probe
CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME
  1      1                           :BEGIN Hello, world
```

PS:

Protip 1: NEVER do `dtrace -n '::: { printf("Hello"); }'` - this means "do a printf on each and every kernel event", and it will completely freeze the kernel; not even CTRL-Alt-Del will work!

Protip 2: If you want to use `DTRACE_DEBUG` as in [Debugging DTrace](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2006/03/30/debugging-dtrace/), use `sudo -E`:

```
dtrace-20130712$ DTRACE_DEBUG=1 sudo -E ./build/dtrace -n 'BEGIN { printf("Hello, world"); exit(0); }'
libdtrace DEBUG: reading kernel .ctf: /path/to/src/dtrace-20130712/build-2.6.38-16-generic/linux-2.6.38-16-generic.ctf
libdtrace DEBUG: opened 32-bit /proc/kallsyms (syms=75761)
...
```